# Getting Started with Reddit open-source, Configuration/Installation

Tags: linux, open-source, vmware, opensuse, reddit

It is always better to learn from other developers experiences. I would like to clone **Reddit** at my workplace on an **intranet** basis. Though the documentation is great at http://code.reddit.com/#GettingStarted , I have not developed or used Linux before, so I am not familiar with using the terminal and Linux commands.

What **OS** should I install (Opensuse, Ubuntu)? Can it be done on Windows?

What is the advantage in using the "**Pre-built VM**"? (VMware)

What is the difference between **fork** and **clone**?

Can anyone point me towards the right direction, in terms on installing the right software and configuring Reddit. I would appreciate any help. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use Linux, [Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/) will work fine, and it has good documentation. It probably cannot be done on Windows.

If your new to Linux, read [Linux System Administrator Basics](http://library.linode.com/using-linux/administration-basics/).

You will probably have to set up a LAMP server. [Here is a good tutorial](http://library.linode.com/lamp-guides/ubuntu-10.04-lucid/).

Make sure you do everything listed [here](http://code.reddit.com/wiki/RedditSetup) too.

Once you have that up, you will need to install git so you can clone the reddit repository. ([github](http://github.com/) is a website where people post code, and git is a command line tool for copying it to your local machine)

you can install git, and other things in Ubuntu with

```
sudo apt-get install git
```

Then you would do

```
git clone http://code.reddit.com/repo/reddit.git
```

That will put all the code in a folder in whatever directory you were working in, follow whatever instructions you find in the README in that folder.

Should you succeed, give yourself a HUGE pat on the back and a vacation.